# Expo migrating to eas build: .html files not loaded as assets with eas build but works with expo:build

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

We are using some `.html`  files as template partsto dynamically create an HTML bigger file.

This HTML is built from some smaller .html pieces. Like this:
[image]

Those .html files are loaded via `require()` like this:
[image]

Seems that `.html` files from assets are not being bundled with eas build

Sentry gives us this error when triying to load those .html templates:

[image]

The `assetBundlePatterns` in the `app.config.json` is like this:
[image]

We have read the documentation but we can´t find any migration from `expo:build` to `eas build` about this..

Thanks!!

The expected result is load the .html template

Answer (score 0):

Solved, my problem.

I was loading the local file with fetch. I hace changed it to FileSystem.readAsStringAsync

//Original

```
    let file: Asset = Asset.fromModule(requiredFile);
    let response: Response = await fetch(file.uri);
    let text = await response.text();
    return text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm, "");
```

//New

```
    const [{ localUri }] = await Asset.loadAsync(requiredFile);
    let text = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(localUri);
    return text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm, "");
```